# How to get user date of birth from a form then get the user age in php mysql

Tags: php, html

How to get user date of birth from a form then get the user age

step:
form inhtml->phpscript->echo age

P.S:if you have a better date picker write is down also

Comment: Read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP >= 5.3.0**

```
# object oriented
$from = new DateTime('1970-02-01');
$to   = new DateTime('today');
echo $from->diff($to)->y;

# procedural
echo date_diff(date_create('1970-02-01'), date_create('today'))->y;
```

[demo](https://eval.in/84187)

functions: `date_create()`, `date_diff()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
calculateYear = function(){
  var b_year = document.getElementById('date').value.split('-')[0]
  var b_month = document.getElementById('date').value.split('-')[1]
  var current_date = new Date()
  var p = document.getElementById('result')
  p.innerHTML = "You are " + (current_date.getFullYear() - b_year) + " year/s and " + ((current_date.getMonth() + 1) - b_month) + " month/s old"
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date">
<button onclick="calculateYear()">calculate</button>
<br>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Here is a solution with html and js only